# Is loop and recursion interchangeable?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, binary-search-tree

A lot of people say loop and recursion is basically the same.  The only difference between two is that some algorithms are easier to understand in recursion or iteration.  Besides, loop is always preferred, because of overhead of function calls.  However, here is a python code to get the height of a binary search tree .  How can I write it using loop?

```py
bst = [(1, 2), (3, None), (None, None), (None, None)]

def recursion_height(tree, v=0):
    if v is None:
        return -1
    else:
        return max(recursion_height(tree, tree[v][0]), recursion_height(tree, tree[v][1])) + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented iteratively using queues.

```
# A binary tree node 
class Node:
# Constructor to create new node 
def __init__(self, data): 
    self.data = data  
    self.left = None
    self.right = None


# Iterative method to find height of Binary Tree 
def treeHeight(root): 

    # Base Case 
    if root is None: 
        return 0

    # Create a empty queue for level order traversal 
    q = [] 

    # Enqueue Root and Initialize Height  
    q.append(root) 
    height = 0 

    while(True):   
        # nodeCount(queue size) indicates number of nodes 
        # at current level 
        nodeCount = len(q) 
        if nodeCount == 0 : 
            return height  

        height += 1 

        # Dequeue all nodes of current level and Enqueue 
        # all nodes of next level 
        while(nodeCount > 0): 
            node = q[0] 
            q.pop(0) 
            if node.left is not None: 
                q.append(node.left) 
            if node.right is not None: 
                q.append(node.right) 

            nodeCount -= 1

# Driver program to test above function 
# Let us create binary tree shown in above diagram 
root = Node(1) 
root.left = Node(2) 
root.right = Node(3) 
root.left.left = Node(4) 
root.left.right = Node(5) 

print "Height of tree is", treeHeight(root)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I’m not sure I can understand your function.  What is the input of your function? Where is the binary search tree?  Could you provide a sample input and output?